# keyboardWillShow is not responding while changing orientation, the cursor is at UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In `iOS6`:

1. Type some comments in UITextView
2. Change orientation while the cursor is in text view

**Observation:** `keyboardWillShow` responded and `textView` scrolled to top and I can see the comments. Things are working fine.

In `iOS7`:

Followed above two steps.
**Observation:** `keyboardWillShow` is not responding. So while changing the orientation `textView` is not scrolling to top.

Should I include any new method for `iOS7`?

My code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {

   RSLogTrace();

   self.textDecorator.isKeyboardSplit = NO;
   CGRect keyboardBounds;
   [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardBounds];
   CGFloat keyboardHeight;
   keyboardHeight = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) ? keyboardBounds.size.height : keyboardBounds.size.width;
   self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight - 5, 0.0);
   self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with TextView when orientation is change, i mean put of it.

Comment: where's the code to scroll the textView to top?

Comment: @StiaticVoidMain: Scroll to top is written in textViewDidBiginEditing.

Answer (score 0):

As per you comments, you have the scrolling logic within `textViewDidBeginEditing:`.

In this case... if you have begun editing the `textView` in a particular orientation and while editing, you rotate the screen then the `textViewDidBeginEditing:` delegate will not fire after rotation because, technically, you had already begun editing it in the previous orientation.

### Solution:

Move the scroll to top logic (*for the required `textView`*)  into the `keyboardWillShow:` method.

---

*PS: when in doubt, breakpoint all the key methods and see how the flow goes*

Comment: Even I move the scroll logic to keyboardWillShow it won't work, because here the problem is the keyboardWillShow method is not responding in iOS7 when we rotate the simulator.

Comment: @selva : are you sure it fires at all? because last time i checked, `keyboardWillShow` does fire after screen rotation. if you haven't registered for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, then it won't. or... you can implement the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method